# TSLint not working with CRA and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, tslint, prettier

I'm banging my head for hours trying to enable linting for a TypeScript project created with create-react-app.

- The [wmonk/create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) repo is now deprecated
- Therefore, I followed [these](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript) instructions from the CRA documentation

The issue is that the suggested implementation above doesn't add any linting to the newly created project.

So far I've tried:

- Installing [TypeScript TSLint Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin) as an extension to my VSCode
- Creating a `tslint.json` file on my project with the following config:

```or-tag
  {
    "rules": {
      "no-debugger": false,
      "no-console": false,
      "interface-name": false
    },
    "linterOptions": {
      "exclude": [
        "config/**/*.js", "node_modules/**/*.ts", "coverage/lcov-report/*.js"
      ]
    },
    "extends": [
      "tslint:recommended", 
      "tslint-react", 
      "tslint-config-prettier"
    ]
  }
```

- Adding a *lint script* to my `package.json`

```js
 "scripts": { 
     "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --fix --format verbose"
 }
```

Then I tried running `yarn lint or npm run lint` but no files get ever linted from any of the approaches above

this is my `package.json` file:

```or-tag
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.11",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --fix --format verbose",
    "tslint-check": "tslint-config-prettier-check ./tslint.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

This is the `tsconfig.json` auto-generated by *npx create-react-app [project-name] --typescript*

```or-tag
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you missing a `tslint.json`? Could you please update the post with the contents of it and what output happens when you run `npm run lint`?

Comment: `tslint.json` is the very first code block added to the post. When I run `npm run lint` I get no errors, therefore no linting either, since I intentionally added typescript errors to test it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had to go through the same process figuring how to get TSLint and Pretter to work on a CRA + TypeScript project.

I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rimatla/a5a2c5dcf831c5744a656cfe81fadf52) with **step-by-step** instructions on how you can set it up accordingly.

The above solution, in a nutshell, is to make sure that you have the appropriate VSCode extensions installed and the appropriate dependencies in your package.json so your changes get tracked by both TSLint and Prettier.

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed. My original set-up was missing more dependencies packages.

Comment: Nicely gathered and structured info in your gist @Jonca33. Thanks, will come in handy!