# Typescript: How to supress any semicolon warnings

Tags: tslint

I want to be like all the cool kids so I desperately want to use typescript. Is there a way to suppress the Unnecessary semicolon warnings, other than not putting in unnecessary semicolons? I don't want tslint complaining either way about semicolons.

My tslint.json:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "warning",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**",
      "src/plugins/**"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "indent": [true, "spaces", 2],
    "interface-name": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "member-access": [true, "no-public"],
    "semicolon": [true, "never"],
    "trailing-comma": "ignore",
    "no-console": false
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want it complaining, why'd you set it to `true`?

Comment: @jhpratt does not matter what its set to, still complains

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out on my machine — using the latest TS and tslint, it appears as though _no_ rules work _at all_.

Comment: @jhpratt yeah, I've tried setting it to all available options, same outcome, pretty annoying

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the tslint extension for vscode.
[vscode-tslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) has been deprecated and suggests this extension [vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin) be used in its place.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034575/tslint-not-working-with-cra-and-typescript) led me to the solution.